# Joomla - Fabrik 3.X - SQL Error

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin

I have fresh install of **Joomla 3.X** and **Fabrik 3** ( Official Package from Fabrik.com). I am new to fabrik and I am curious to find out its capabilities.

If Fabrik fails me , I will drop using Joomla and switch back to CodeIgniter.

I want to load a simple SQL data table ( localhost ) and set some filter fields to start with but I have been having this error which I cannot figure out the cause.

```
   0 SQL=ALTER TABLE `tablename` COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

I have created a simple list and loaded the corresponding database table but whenever I try to make any changes, I receive the above Error Message.

At the frontend the table is loading, but I fail to configure anything.

Database : Phpmyadmin 5.5
Store Engine Type : InnoDb
Collation : utf8_general_ci

Any idea what's wrong in my settings ? Any good alternative to Fabrik for Joomla ?

Comment: Fabrik is not compatible with Joomla 3.x.

Comment: Yes it is - Check their Website and Github, a Fabrik 3.1b is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabrik does not accept numeric table names.

I modified my tablename from 33665 to p_33665 and the problem has been solved.

I hope this can help new Fabrik users.